# WCF service In JAVA

Tags: java, c#, wcf

I already created WPF(C#) apps

> 1) Server 2) Client

both has it's own TCP endpoints

Server Contract

```
public interface IServer
{
    //Client calls this to register it self in server.
    [OperationContract]
    void RegisterClient(string hostName, string domainName);
    //To submit the resut back to server.
    [OperationContract]
    void SubmitResult(Result result);            
    //heart beat check, to check the client is alive.
    bool ConnectionTest();
}
```

Client Contract

```
interface IClient
{
    //Heart beat check, to check the server is alive.
    [OperationContract()]
    bool IsAvailable();        
    [OperationContract()]
    void dosomething(string projects);
}
```

Both the server and client are working fine. This there is any way i can create a Client app in java with above client Contract which will interact with WPF(C#) server?

I think java supports tcp and SOAP, is there is any WCF Equivalent framework in JAVA(a console app)?

i am new to java i don't know where to begin with.

Comment: As I know C# can use java code but java can't use c# because there not enough libraries in java)
But here is some example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777036/Consuming-WCF-Service-in-Java-Client

Comment: Check out Apache CXF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binding choice**

`NetTcpBinding` is a binary Microsoft technology.

In order to call the Net service with Java, you should favour:

- `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP 1.1)
- `wsHttpBinding` (SOAP 1.2)

**Metadata**

Don't forget to expose Metadata Exchange in order for your WSDL to  be called

Metadata Endpoint :

```
<services>
  <service name="BillingService.BillingService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    ...
</service>
```

Metadata Behavior :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior>
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      ...
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

**Generation of the proxy in java :**

Then use wsimport.exe from %JavaRoot%\bin

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin>wsimport.exe -s e:\temp\javaws http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/BillingService/?wsdl
```

Regards

Comment: @Balakrishnan, did it help ?